# uirefreshcontrol not showing when tableview has many rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

my demo code is very simple:i want to load from network when the view controller is present , so i have to call beginRefreshing manually from viewdidload to show the loading refreshControl at beginning

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIRefreshControl* control;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

    self.control = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.control];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.control beginRefreshing];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

and If i just set number of sections to 1(total rows is 3), every things goes well 
[image]

but if i change number of sections to a bigger number like 10(total rows is 30) , the refresh control will not show

[image]

is it a system bug ? or the way i use refresh control is wrong ?

Comment: Please post code not screenshot of code.

Comment: @Leo OK， i've already post the code now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its showing even with 10 sections with 30 rows each.
The problem is its getting hidden at top.
Try this:

```
self.control = [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.control];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.control beginRefreshing];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:true];
```

And i dont know why do you want to show loading initial. It has to be triggered on user action of pulldown. Then you do page data refresh and reload the page.
You should also consider adding

```
-(void)setUpRefreshControl
{
    self.control = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.control];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
//    [self.control beginRefreshing];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:true];
    [ self.control addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)refresh {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        //Do data refresh task here like getting new data for UI.
        sleep(1);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.control endRefreshing];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: because in the real code , i want to load from network when the view controller  is present , so i want the refresh control to be seen at the beginning , so i have to manually set the content offset to achieve this?

Comment: do you think it's some kinda of system bug？

Comment: U'll have to change the offset to achieve this as i mentioned. Because UIRefreshControl and UITableView works independently.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove this line
```

self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];

and do like this

```
self.control  =  [UIRefreshControl new];
[self.tableView addSubview: self.control];
[ self.control addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)refresh {
    //refresh your data
    [self.control endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: want to load from network when the view controller is present , so i have to call beginRefreshing manually from viewdidload